# MySQL query result in query order

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to execute a query which contains if and case statements in select clause, and the result I am getting is grouped, for each row contains an element with index 0 which is an array and it contains all the fields that are without if/case and the ones with if/case are in associative array with table name as the key... I am using [CakePHP model's query method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query).

Here is a part of my query

```
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 4, request.creation_time), '%e-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S') As 'Request Date Received',
    request.request_uuid As 'Customer Id',
    contact_information.person_name As 'Customer Name',
    service_type.id As 'service_types',
    service.id AS 'lead_types',
    IFNULL(user.username, 'N/A') As 'Internal Owner of lead',
    request.request_status As 'status_types',
    IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 4, request_activity.creation_time), '%e-%m-%Y'), 'N/A') AS 'Date of last status',
    IFNULL(request_activity.comment, 'N/A') As comment_on_status_internal
```

And the result looks like this

```
2014-03-10 16:57:32 Debug: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Request Date Received] => 10-02-2014 01:49:02
                    [Internal Owner of lead] => rea
                    [Date of last status] => 10-02-2014
                    [Time of last status] => 18:39:56
                )

            [request] => Array
                (
                    [Customer Id] => 20140210000001DR
                    [status_types] => 10
                )

            [contact_information] => Array
                (
                    [Customer Name] => Jihane
                )

            [service_type] => Array
                (
                    [service_types] => Move
                )

        )

    [1] => Array ....
```

And I want to result to look like this

```
    2014-03-10 16:57:32 Debug: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
                    [Request Date Received] => 10-02-2014 01:49:02
                    [Customer Id] => 20140210000001DR
                    [Customer Name] => Jihane
                    [service_types] => Move
                    [Internal Owner of lead] => rea
                    [Date of last status] => 10-02-2014
                    [Time of last status] => 18:39:56
                    [status_types] => 10

        )

    [1] => Array ...
```

I have tried the queries without any case statements, it looks good but if I add the IF/CASE it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP's model query method returns an associative array by default. Your indexed return values are interesting. There may be a CakePHP method to return a different array. You can research that if you like. In the meantime, here's a way to flatten your array. This assumes that your array is stored in the variable $results:

```
foreach ($results as $rkey => $rvalue) {//0 => array, 1 => array
    foreach ($rvalue as $key => $value) {//0, request, contact_information...
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

            //move element to first sub-array slot
            $results[$rkey][$k] = $v;

            //unset associative element in sub-array
            unset($results[$rkey][$key][$k]);
        }
        //unset associative element in array
        unset($results[$rkey][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem, in this case the order from the query is lost, actually I want the same order.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use virtualfields

assuming you are in RequestsController

```
$this->Request->virtualFields['Internal_Owner_of_lead'] = "IFNULL(user.username, 'N/A')";
$this->Request->virtualFields['Date_of_last_status'] = "IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 4, request_activity.creation_time), '%e-%m-%Y'), 'N/A')";
// etc ....

$data = $this->Request->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Request.Internal_Owner_of_lead', 
            'Request.Date_of_last_status',
            // other fields here
        )
    )
);
```

then you can use hash to get an indexed array

```
$data = Hash::extract($data, '{n}.Request');
```